# Making a slow code with symbolic manipulations faster

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic, code-review

I have a code with symbolic manipulations. It works fine but very slow (e.g. for `w=14` it's reasonably fast but I want it to work for `w=40`, say.). I don't have good understanding of what operations make a Mathematica code slow. Here is a baby version of the code. Suggestions will be appreciated.

(I have used `=!=` symbol in this code. Does it make the code slower?)

```
 $Assumptions = a > 0 && z > 0;
 ch[h_, z_] := (z^(h + 1/2) - z^(-h - 1/2))/(z^(1/2) - z^(-(1/2))) 
 Z[q_, z_] := (q^(1/2) (1 - q^2))/((1 - q) (1 - q z) (1 - q z^-1))
 w = 14;
 prim = 0;
 poly = Series[(Exp[Sum[1/n Z[a^2^n, z^n], {n, 1, 2 w}]] -
     1 - Z[a^2, z] - 
     Sum[ (a^2^(l + 1) ch[l, z] - 
       a^(2 (l + 2))
         ch[l - 1, z])/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1)), {l,
        2, w, 2}] -
     Expand[y prim] /. {y^x_ ->   
      ch[x - 1, 
       z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1))} /. {y ->   
     ch[0, z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1))}), {a, 0, 
  w}] // Simplify // Normal;
 prim =  0;
 For[p = 2, p <= w, p++,
 polyz = Coefficient[poly, a, p];
 hpow = Exponent[polyz, z];
 While[(hpow != 0)  && 
 (polyz =!= 0),
 hcoeff = Coefficient[polyz, z, hpow];
 prim = prim + a^p hcoeff y^hpow;
 poly = Series[(Exp[Sum[1/n Z[a^2^n, z^n], {n, 1, 2 w}]] -
       1 - Z[a^2, z] - 
       Sum[ (a^2^(l + 1) ch[l, z] - 
         a^(2 (l + 2))

           ch[l - 1, z])/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - 
           a^2 z^-1)), {l, 2, w, 2}] - 

       Expand[y prim] /. {y^x_ ->   
        ch[x - 1, 
         z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1))} /. {y ->   
       ch[0, z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1))}), {a, 0, 
    w}] // Simplify // Normal;
 polyz = Coefficient[poly, a, p];
 hpow = Exponent[polyz, z]
 ];
 prim = prim + a^p polyz;
 ];
 Print["Prim = ", Collect[prim /. {y -> z}, a]];
```

Comment: I think you'll get better suggestions if you explain what the code does. As it stands now, it is very hard to guess your intent behind the code. And I think `=!=` is the least of your problems - `SameQ` essentially only needs to compare two expressions.

Comment: I would evaluate this one expression at a time.  This will give you a clue about which evaluation is time consuming.

Comment: @mikado the second expression is far more time consuming than the first one.

Comment: Mathematica interprets `a^2^n` as `a^(2^n)`.  Do you actually mean that, or  `(a^2)^n`?

Comment: Yes. I noticed that. It should be `a^{2n}`.

Comment: Then, should `a^2^(l + 1)` also be `a^(2 (l + 1))`?

Comment: Yes. It happened while copying the code. Anyway the code works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following reduces the `AbsoluteTiming` of the calculation a factor of five on my computer.

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && z > 0;
ch[h_, z_] = (z^(h + 1) - z^(-h))/(z - 1) ;
Z[q_, z_] = (q^(1/2) (1 + q))/((1 - q z) (1 - q z^-1));
w = 14;
t1 = Simplify[Series[Exp[Sum[1/n Z[a^2^n, z^n], {n, 1, 2 w}]] - 1 - Z[a^2, z] - 
     Sum[ (a^2^(l + 1) ch[l, z] - a^(2 (l + 2)) ch[l - 1, z])/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) 
     (1 - a^2 z^-1)), {l, 2, w, 2}], {a, 0,  w}], a > 0 && z > 0]; // AbsoluteTiming

prim =  0; poly = t1;
Do[polyz = Coefficient[poly, a, p]; hpow = Exponent[polyz, z];
While[(hpow != 0) && (polyz =!= 0), 
    hcoeff = Coefficient[polyz, z, hpow]; prim = prim + a^p hcoeff y^hpow;
poly = Simplify[t1 - Series[ 
    Expand[y prim] /. {y^x_ -> ch[x - 1, z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1)), 
    y ->  ch[0, z]/((1 - a^2) (1 - a^2 z) (1 - a^2 z^-1))}, {a,  0,  w}], 
    a > 0 && z > 0] // Normal ;
polyz = Coefficient[poly, a, p]; hpow = Exponent[polyz, z]];
prim = prim + a^p polyz;, {p, 2, w}] // AbsoluteTiming

Collect[prim /. {y -> z}, a]
```

The most substantive change is to move the two `Sum`s, now designated `t1`, out of the `While` loop and then `Simplify` it.  Replacing `SetDelayed` by `Set` in the definitions of the two functions and simplifying them by hand also helps a bit.  Note that the time required to compute `t1` exceeds the time required to compute the entire `Do` loop and increases rapidly with `w`.  So, further improvements in speed are to be achieved by optimizing the `t1` computation.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey! It's faster than before.